# Need help adding a $PATH variable

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, emacs

I want to add `/data/biocs/b/bio425/bin` to the `$PATH` variable in the `.bash_profile` file (using `vi` or `emacs`).

What I have done so far is

```bsh
vi .bash_profile
```

and then I attempted to add `/data/biocs/b/bio425/bin` to my `$PATH`:

```bsh
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:../../bio425/bp-utils
export PATH

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:../../data/biocs/b/bio425/bin
export PATH
```

I then saved and of course sourced the file.
Next I tried to run the command `long-orf mystery_seq1`, but I got

```bsh
long-orf: command not found
```

Am I doing something wrong with my `$PATH` variable?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really new to this site and I'm not sure why I got a down vote, if i included too much or too little information it would be great to know!

Comment: I don't think the downvote was justified. Anyway I would expect a downvoter to explain what is wrong with the question. Your question is understandably a bit on the basic  side but you have explained what you want to do, what you have already tried, and what goes wrong. I admit that the original title wasn't spot on, and the formatting was a bit off, but that is not unusual here and has been corrected by a friendly editor. I'll give you an upvote to balance out the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not use relative paths in `$PATH`. Well, you may, but each time the system then tries to look up a command, it will try to resolve the relative path entry there based on your current working directory, which can be anything.

Also don't duplicate the `$HOME/bin` entry.

Note that normally you place your custom paths in front of the default (i.e. before the old `$PATH`), so that they have higher priority. I don't know if it is intended that you put them last.

You don't need to re-export the variable either, this one is already exported (although it doesn't hurt).

So all you need should be to change the second half of your file to this:

```bsh
# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH="$HOME/bin:/data/biocs/b/bio425/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: thanks! everything seems to be working now, appreciate your help!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the grey check button on its left. You also mark your question as solved that way. Thanks.